# Accessing incoming POST data in Flask

Tags: python, curl, flask

Here's the flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def refresh():
    params = {
        'thing1': request.values.get('thing1'),
        'thing2': request.values.get('thing2')
    }
    return json.dumps(params)
```

Here's the `cURL`:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?thing1=1' -d '{"thing2":2}'                                              
> {"thing1": "1", "thing2": null}

$ curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?thing1=1' -d '{"thing2":2}'                                              
> {"thing1": "1", "thing2": null}
```

The [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data) seem VERY clear that this should be working:

> form
>
> A MultiDict with the parsed form data from POST or PUT requests.
>   Please keep in mind that file uploads will not end up here, but
>   instead in the files attribute.
>
> args
>
> A MultiDict with the parsed contents of the query string. (The
>   part in the URL after the question mark).
>
> values
>
> A CombinedMultiDict with the contents of both form and args.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Update: Trying suggestions from one of the answers, swapping out the `return` line:

Using `return json.dumps(json.load(request.body.decode("utf-8") ))` generates the error `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'body'`

Using `return json.dumps(json.load(request.json))` generates the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'`

Using `POST` with the origin code appears to have no effect:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?thing1=1' -d '{"thing2":2}'
{"thing1": "1", "thing2": null}
```

Setting the content type and using `POST` with the original code also has no apparent effect:

```
$ curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?thing1=1' -d '{"thing2":2}' 
{"thing1": "1", "thing2": null}
```

although I went and verified that the content-type was then correctly set:

```
...
print(request.headers)
...

Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 12
```

Comment: `curl -X GET` sends a GET request ... you need `curl -X POST`

Comment: Thanks, but not helpful. I explicitly want to send a GET with JSON in the request body.

Comment: Instead of `request.values` did you try `request.get_json()` because it works if you set `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Comment: `request.json` provides a parsed dictionary, not a string, which is why `json.load` is failing. I also incorrectly stated that the POST raw text body was stored in `request.body` when it's actually stored in `request.data`. The original answer has been updated to correct this.

Comment: Ah. I suspect that would also cause a problem, but as the error is "NoneType.." seems like the problem is not that `json.load` is trying to load a dictionary, but that it is trying to load a `None`. Regardless, my issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're inadvertently sending the wrong [Content Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types).

By default, [`curl`'s `-d` flag will send POST data with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d). Since you're not sending data in the format that it's expecting (*key=value*), it's dropping the data altogether. For JSON data, you'll need to send the HTTP request with the content-type set to `application/json` like so:

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?thing1=1' -d '{"thing2":2}'
```

Also, flask's `request.form` field only contains [POST form data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms), not other content types. You can access the raw POST request body with [`request.data`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.data) or, more convenienty, the parsed JSON data using [`request.get_json`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.get_json).

Below is a fixed version of your example:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def refresh():
    params = {
        'thing1': request.values.get('thing1'),
        'thing2': request.get_json().get('thing2')
    }
    return json.dumps(params)


app.run()
```

UPDATE: I misspoke earlier - `request.body` should actually be `request.data`. Also as it turns out [`request.json` is deprecated](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.json) and `request.get_json` should be used now instead. The original post has been updated.

Comment: Works. But, I hate Flask (and Python) a little more now. It has strong, undocumented opinions about how things should be, and is not apologetic or kind to learning those opinions. Anyway, thanks, @jtimmons