# How to send AJAX request from Javascript/React and receive data in Python REST API

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, rest, flask

I have my front end code written in react. I have a simple for where a user can fill out their name, title, department, and other basic string fields like that. When the user hits submit I have my javascript create an AJAX request to my REST API written in python+flask. When the request comes in however there is no data associated with the request.

I have tried printing every combination of the request object in python, but each comes back as either None, '', or an empty byte string.

react code:

```
class AddPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
        }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = '/api';
        Http.open("POST", url);
        Http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        Http.send(this.state);

        Http.onreadystatechange = e => {
            window.location.replace("/add");
        }
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const targetName = event.target.name;
        const value = target.value;

        this.setState({
            [targetName]: value,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="addUser">
                <label>
                Name:
                <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                </label>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Python REST API

```
from flask_classful import FlaskView, route
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

class API(FlaskView):
    route_base = '/api'

    def post(self):
        if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
            print("before")
            posted_data = request.get_json()
            print("after")
            print(posted_data)
```

The before gets printed, but not the after or posted data. When I run that code as is by just returning 'Done' I get this in the server log

`before
[pid: 32472|app: 0|req: 12/12] 127.0.0.1 () {46 vars in 739 bytes} [Fri Aug 23 13:35:32 2019] POST /api/ => generated 192 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 400) 2 headers in 74 bytes (1 switches on core 0)` So I know it receives the POST request properly, but I am unable to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data out of the request object inside your Flask service's method

```
def post(self):
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
        posted_data = request.get_json()
        print(posted_data)
```

Comment: When I do that I get this as a response `[pid: 32020|app: 0|req: 28/28] 127.0.0.1 () {46 vars in 738 bytes} [Fri Aug 23 12:05:06 2019] POST /api/ => generated 192 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 400) 2 headers in 74 bytes (1 switches on core 0)` and the terminal does not print anything

Comment: Ah .. according to this answer, request.json is deprecated; use get_json() instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273205/accessing-incoming-post-data-in-flask

Comment: I changed it to get_json() and it still prints before and returns a 400 error `before
[pid: 32472|app: 0|req: 12/12] 127.0.0.1 () {46 vars in 739 bytes} [Fri Aug 23 13:35:32 2019] POST /api/ => generated 192 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 400) 2 headers in 74 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`